# ASP.NET MVC - User access for directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

How can I add limited access to only 1 specific user has access to 1 specific directory and none else can access it than him? I've looked at the web.config thing but that wont work.

So basically what I'm trying to is:

Person creates user => new user => new directory (access ONLY for the new user and none else).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application I am currently working on uses the Authorize decoration in conjunction with the membership and role providers (both custom) to manage access to pages within my MVC site e.g.

```
[Authorize(Users="MyUsername")]
public ActionResult Banking()
{
   return View();
}

[Authorize(Roles="SysAdmin, BusinessOwner")]
public ActionResult Banking()
{
   return View();
}
```

I find this is extremely flexible as you can have public (no decoration) any logged in user [Authorize] or roles & users. Personally I would never build an app that authorized on Users - Roles is a much more extensible option (even if it does only contain one user at the moment) there are two main reasons I wouldn't do this - Users becomes unwieldy in a big app and secondly adding a user to the decoration requires a recompile/redeploy of the app whereas associating a user to a role in most situation is typically a database association that the app's business logic handles at runtime.

In your web.config you set up something similar to this to use the custom providers:

```
 <system.web>
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembership" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyMembership" type="MyDAL.MyMembership, MyDAL"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="MyRole" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyRole" type="MyDAL.MyRole, MyDAL" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Then you create classes that inherit the providers:

```
using System.Web.Security;

namespace MyDAL
{
    class MyMembership : MembershipProvider//[ctrl + .] to create stubs
    {
        //Use Visual Studio to generate all the MembershipProvider stubs [ctrl + .]
    }
}
```

You will end up with a bunch of methods with throw new NotImplementedException() - there are heaps of these but it is not necessary to fill them all out - just complete the ones that are relevant to your application and leave the rest as is.